# Linking three tables to another table using the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I have parents, learners and teachers as tables. Now I have created a users table with user id column. I want to link the three tables to the users table using the user id as the foreign key with cascade on update and on delete. I have tried many ways but I can not add a user because of the foreign key constraint. Does anyone one know a work around?

[image: schema]

Regards,
Joel K.

Comment: I have added a schema to make the question more understandable.

Comment: user_id needs to be a field in the other three tables, and that needs to be a foreign key that references `users(id)`

Comment: Lol-that makes more sense. I think I need a break so I can think straight. Thanks m8